# Como realizo actualizo un campo de mi tabla resultado de una consulta y filtrando por un campo de esa consulta

Tags: mysql

tengo esta consulta funcionándome en SQL y deseo ejecutarla en mysql pero genera el error:

> Error Code: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
> (   select  max(rse.id) as id ,rse.idcempleados,max(rse.idcSucursales) as...' at line 2

```
UPDATE cempleados SET idcSucursal=sub.idcSucursales
FROM 
(   SELECT  MAX(rse.id) AS id ,rse.idcempleados,MAX(rse.idcSucursales) AS idcSucursales,MAX(rse.fechainicia) AS fechainicia 
    FROM relsucursalEmpleado rse 
    INNER JOIN cempleados ce ON ce.id=rse.idcempleados
    WHERE rse.estado=1 AND ce.estado=1
    AND CURDATE() >= rse.fechainicia 
    AND rse.fechainicia >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY)  
    GROUP BY rse.idcempleados
) sub
WHERE sub.idcempleados = cempleados.id
```

Estas tablas, que ocupo son reales en sql server y se esta ejecutando de forma correcta, pero tengo la necesidad de hacer lo mismo , con las mismas tablas (creadas) en mysql y no me funciona y mi duda es si es posible realizar este tipo de consultas en mysql.

Comment: Esa sintaxis no es correcta para un UPDATE. La estructura base es `UPDATE... SET a=b, c=d,... WHERE x=y, z=1,...`. Para una mejor respuesta, por favor amplía la pregunta yendo a [edit]  y cuéntanos sobre qué tablas trabajas y qué deseas que pase al ejecutar el update

Comment: Estas tablas, que ocupo son reales en sql server y se esta ejecutando de forma correcta, pero tengo la necesidad de hacer lo mismo , con las mismas tablas (creadas) en mysql y no me funciona y mi duda es si es posible realizar este tipo de consultas en mysql.

Comment: No sabemos cuál es la consulta que sí funciona en SQLServer, estás probado exactamente lo mismo? Entiendo que quieres usar una subconsulta como fuente del dato que usas para actualizar. Es eso?

Comment: Si deseo utilizar la misma consulta con las mismas tablas pero en mysql (es una migración de un sistema), pero veo que no funciona en mysql y no se si existe alguna solución sin hacer un siclo y un update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es actualizar un solo registro la respuesta de hArrY debe funcionar, pero si lo que quieres es actualizar varios registros con esa consulta deberías cambiar la sintaxis a algo más o menos así:

```
UPDATE cempleados as ce INNER JOIN relsucursalEmpleado as rse ON ce.id=rse.idcempleados 
SET ce.idcSucursal=sub.idcSucursales 
WHERE rse.estado=1 AND ce.estado=1 AND CURDATE() >= rse.fechainicia  
AND rse.fechainicia >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY) 
GROUP BY rse.idcempleados
```

Te comparto de una pregunta en ingles donde menciona la sintaxis que te comento: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan Luis, super bien, me ayudo mucho a solucionar

Comment: UPDATE cempleados AS ce
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT  
 rse.idcempleados 
 ,rse.fechainicia AS fechainicia 
 ,rse.idcSucursales AS idcSucursales
 FROM relsucursalEmpleado rse 
 INNER JOIN cempleados ce ON ce.id=rse.idcempleados
 WHERE rse.estado=1 AND ce.estado=1

 AND CURDATE() >= rse.fechainicia 
 AND rse.fechainicia >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY) 
 ORDER BY rse.fechainicia DESC LIMIT 1 
) sub ON ce.id=sub.idcempleados 
SET ce.idcSucursal=sub.idcSucursales

Comment: Excelente @Rafael Amaro, un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

No deberias usar el alias y el from.
seria update cempleados set idSucursal = (select resultado blabla) where condicion
algo asi

`UPDATE cempleados SET idcSucursal=
(SELECT  MAX(rse.id) AS id ,rse.idcempleados,MAX(rse.idcSucursales) AS idcSucursales,MAX(rse.fechainicia) AS fechainicia
FROM relsucursalEmpleado rse
INNER JOIN cempleados ce ON ce.id=rse.idcempleados
WHERE rse.estado=1 AND ce.estado=1
AND CURDATE() >= rse.fechainicia
AND rse.fechainicia >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY)

GROUP BY rse.idcempleados)
WHERE sub.idcempleados = cempleados.id`